# Pandas: Union strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`

```
ID  active_seconds  domain  subdomain   search_engine   search_term
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    35  vk.com  vk.com  None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    54  vk.com  vk.com  None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    34  vk.com  vk.com  None    None
16c28c057720ab9fbbb5ee53357eadb7    4   facebook.com    facebook.com    None    None
16c28c057720ab9fbbb5ee53357eadb7    4   facebook.com    facebook.com    None    None
16c28c057720ab9fbbb5ee53357eadb7    8   facebook.com    facebook.com    None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    16  megarand.ru megarand.ru None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    6   vk.com  vk.com  None    None
```

I need to change `df`. If to `ID` `subdomain[i] == subdomain[i-1]` I should union this string and `active_seconds[i-1] + active_seconds[i]`. 
From this df I want to get

```
ID  active_seconds  domain  subdomain   search_engine   search_term
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    123 vk.com  vk.com  None    None
16c28c057720ab9fbbb5ee53357eadb7    16  facebook.com    facebook.com    None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    16  megarand.ru megarand.ru None    None
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    6   vk.com  vk.com  None    None
```

What sould I use to do it?

Comment: Why weren't the last two lines joined together?

Comment: @unutbu because `domain[i] != domain[i-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This get's real close.  Not sure if getting that order correct is important to you.

Also, I made an assumption that I should `groupby` `ID`.  This means that if the same `ID` spans across another `ID` and still in the same subdomain, I'll aggregate the `active_seconds`.

```
def proc_id(df):
    cond = df.subdomain != df.subdomain.shift()
    part = cond.cumsum()
    df_ = df.groupby(part).first()
    df_.active_seconds = df.groupby(part).active_seconds.sum()
    return df_

df.groupby('ID').apply(proc_id).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you say,  if I have a list: `lst_domain = ['vkontakte.ru', 'yandex.ru', 'vk.com', 'moscow.vk.com', 'city-link.ru']` and I need if `domain`  is equal some of this list, I should use that, but if for example domain in df is equal `msk.city-link.ru` I should write, how it write in `lst.domain`. I mean in list I have `city-link.ru` but in df `msk.city-link.ru`. And I should rewrite it like in a list

Comment: This seems to be a different question?  You should ask a new question asking about this specifically.

Comment: @piRSquared Is there something like a complex one line solution.